# Upload folder to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I would like to upload a folder with more than 100,000 files (more than 30GB), from my remote server to Google Cloud Storage.
On the server I have I can not install gsutil.
Is there a better way to upload the files? Using the API, that's how it is.

```
 $files = scanDir::scan("../../system_flex/Faturas/Media/", false, true);

$data = array();
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $arquivo = str_replace("//", "/", str_replace("../../system_flex/Faturas/", "", str_replace("\\", "/", $file)));
    $upload = $bucket->upload(
       fopen($file, 'r'), array( 'name' => $arquivo )
    );
}
```

That way it creates many requests and is slow, is there any other way maybe using PHP or some program?

Comment: You want to be as multi-threaded as possible. Round trip time between you and the server is gonna be a big deal here. Honestly it might end up saving time to bundle it all into a tarball, get that one big file into GCS or a GCE instance, unbundle it, and then use gsutil.

Comment: Cool, I'm going to upload the .tar file and unzip, what would be the unzip command in Cloud Storage? I use gsutil on my computer, right?

Comment: Is your server accessible remotely? Could you use the [Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/)?

Comment: I was trying to install but had not got it, the required Python version was 2.7, I installed an older version of gcloud that supported Python 2.6, it's working now

Answer (score 0):

Move file  remote server to google cloud storage is taken less time so you can use above code.

i tested